# CRM fetchxml - AggregateQueryRecordLimit exceeded

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I am accessing dynamics CRM data via fetchxml in c#. When I try to execute the following query I am getting below error.

> AggregateQueryRecordLimit exceeded. Cannot perform this operation.

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false' aggregate='true'>
  <entity name='productclass'>
     <attribute name='classificationidid' groupby='true' alias='classidid'/>
     <attribute name='productidid' aggregate='count' alias='ProductCount' />
      <filter type='and'>
       <condition attribute='classidid' operator='in'>" + cIds + @"</condition>
      </filter>
  </entity>
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that the entity `productclass` contains more records than the current limit in the `AggregateQueryRecordLimit` setting.

You can change this by using the powershell extensions described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a4061cd-e6b4-4672-8c44-20a27c523718

A complete list of settings is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334634.aspx
Remember though that changing this setting could affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

CRM is trying to save itself from choking on a disproportionate amount of data.

What I'd suggest as an attempt at optimizing the process would be to run multiple queries, one for each element of `cIds` (thus switching from `in` to `eq` operator, IIRC). You'll end up with one result set for each element, which you'll be able to merge in code (this is simple with LINQ).

Another suggestion I have is for you to upgrade the CRM: in the latest versions you have Rollup Fields which are designed exactly for doing aggregations on related records.